How to remove a `std::thread` from a container when it's finished?
There is a std::list<std::thread> in a class with another thread which can add some. How to handle the responsibility to remove a thread element from the list when it's finished ?
I thought about another thread which can be notified by a finishing thread to do so, but it appears to become complicated to me and I am not sure if I'm missing something and the whole thing may just be a bad idea.

when the thread is finished it should just put its iterator in a vector of "to_be_deleted_nodes", and when creating a new thread you just clear elements from both lists, should be O(1) and no traversal required, just remember to use locks.

Put the std::thread in a struct or class that has a bool member which the thread can set when finished, then change the std::list to hold that struct/class, and then you can iterate the list periodically removing items whose bool has been set.

If you've already joined a few of the threads in the list, you could just remove them with std::erase_if(thread_list, [](auto& th) { return not th.joinable(); }); I suppose

The tricky part will be making sure the thread really has finished, and hasn't just set the remove me flag and then hung.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

if you are okay with having locks you can just keep track of whatever threads you need to delete in a queue and every time you want to create a new thread you just delete the finished ones.
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <list>
#include <queue>

struct manager
{
    void spawn()
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard l(mut);
            // remove finished theads
            while (threads_to_destroy.size())
            {
                auto& thread_it = threads_to_destroy.front();
                (*thread_it).join();
                threads.erase(thread_it);
                threads_to_destroy.pop();
            }
        }
        
        // create new thread at the end and get its iterator
        auto it = threads.insert(threads.end(), std::thread{});

        // start the thread with a finalizer
        auto finalizer = [this, it]() {
            std::lock_guard l(this->mut);
            this->threads_to_destroy.push(it);
        };
        *it = std::thread([finalizer](){
            // do work
            finalizer();
            });
    }
    std::list<std::thread> threads;
    std::queue<std::list<std::thread>::iterator> threads_to_destroy;
    std::mutex mut;
    ~manager()
    {
        for (auto& item: threads)
        {
            if (item.joinable())
            {
                item.join();
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    manager m;
    m.spawn();
    m.spawn();
    m.spawn();
}

disadvantages:

exception safety could be improved
old threads are not freed till a new one is created
uses locks
unbounded time for spawn

advantages:

thread-safe, with no race conditions
can remove the lock if the queue is replaced with a lock-free one


Threads put into threads_to_destroy need to be joined.  Your code doesn't do it.  That should be an easy fix.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont fixed, thank you, i mostly use jthread
